# "unbound module Base" in VS Code with ocaml-lsp

Tags: visual-studio-code, ocaml, language-server-protocol

I have Ocaml switch 4.13.1 running on Mac. utop is working fine, can load the Base module when I do:

```
#use "topfind";;
#require "base";;
open Base
List.mem ["1"] "1" ~equal:String.equal
```

even though I followed these instructions https://dev.realworldocaml.org/install.html which assume I don't have even to do `open Base`, but the VS Code is having a problem loading the Base module. I have OCaml -LSP language server installed for VS code for the switch I have. But when I try the above code, it gives me red error squiggly line under the `#` of `#use "topfind";;`. When I remove `use` and `require` I get the following error in the screenshot attached. Can you please help with this? I have tried everything since yesterday, I tried to build a project with dune and still in the main the above code have squiggly lines.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

From what you've shown, it looks like you're trying to use `#require` and `#use` in an OCaml program, This is not correct. They are functions of the toplevel, but not part of the OCaml language itself.

When actually compiling or running a whole program, you'd either want to use ocamlfind or the libraries stanza in dune.